# The pug mixin doesn't return the expected content

Tags: vue.js, pug, quasar-framework

I'm new in pug and have an issue. We use pug in Vue.js application and I want to generate the multi level menu (with submenus). We use data that looks as following:

```
mounted () {
  this.catalog = [
    {
      title: "Компрессоры",
      permalink: "kompressory",
      hasChildren: true,
      cover: "kk",
      subcatalog: [
        {
          title: "A1",
          permalink: "a1",
          hasChildren: false,
          cover: "aa1",
        },
        {
          title: "B1",
          permalink: "b1",
          hasChildren: false,
          cover: "bb1",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Ручной инструмент",
      permalink: "ruchnoy-instrument",
      hasChildren: true,
      cover: "rr",
      subcatalog: [
        {
          title: "C1",
          permalink: "c1",
          hasChildren: false,
          cover: "cc1",
        },
        {
          title: "D1",
          permalink: "d1",
          hasChildren: false,
          cover: "dd1",
        },
        {
          title: "E1",
          permalink: "e1",
          hasChildren: false,
          cover: "ee1",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Пневмоинструмент",
      permalink: "pnevmoinstrument",
      hasChildren: false,
      cover: "pp",
    },
    {
      title: "Специальный инструмент",
      permalink: "spetsialnyy-instrument",
      hasChildren: false,
      cover: "ss",
    },
    {
      title: "Оборудование для СТО",
      permalink: "garazhnoe-oborudovanie",
      hasChildren: false,
      cover: "oo",
    },
  ]
}
```

It should be vertical menu with a button on top. When you click a button, the menu with submenus drops down. As menu component we use Quasar's QMenu.

The working template code looks as following:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .q-pa-md
    .q-gutter-md.row.items-center

      q-btn(color='primary', label='Click me')
        q-menu(v-model='showing')
          q-list(dense='dense', style='min-width: 100px')
            q-item(v-for='category in catalog', :key='category.permalink', href='#', clickable='clickable', v-close-popup='v-close-popup')
              q-item-section {{ category.title }}
              q-item-section(side='side')
                q-icon(name='keyboard_arrow_right', v-if='category.hasChildren')
              q-menu(anchor='top end', self='top start')
                q-list
                  q-item(v-for='n in 3', :key='n', dense='dense', clickable='clickable')
                    q-item-section Submenu Label
                    q-item-section(side='side')
                      q-icon(name='keyboard_arrow_right')
                    q-menu(auto-close='auto-close', anchor='top end', self='top start')
                      q-list
                        q-item(v-for='n in 3', :key='n', dense='dense', clickable='clickable')
                          q-item-section 3rd level Label
            q-separator
            q-item(clickable='clickable', v-close-popup='v-close-popup')
              q-item-section Quit
</template>
```

The screenshot:

[image]

But, I wrote createMenu.pug mixin that looks as following:

```
mixin createMenu(catalog)
  q-list(dense style='min-width: 100px')
    q-item(v-for='category in catalog', :key='category.permalink', href='#', clickable='clickable', v-close-popup='v-close-popup')
      q-item-section {{ category.title }}
      q-item-section(side='side')
        q-icon(name='keyboard_arrow_right', v-if='category.hasChildren')
```

As you can see, I've just moved the part of code from main template to mixin and that's it.

But, when I try to use that mixin in main template in this way:

```
<template lang="pug">
  include ./pug_mixins/createMenu.pug

  .q-pa-md
    .q-gutter-md.row.items-center
      q-btn(color='primary', label='Click me')
        q-menu(v-model='showing')
          +createMenu(catalog)
            q-menu(anchor='top end', self='top start')
              q-list
                q-item(v-for='n in 3', :key='n', dense='dense', clickable='clickable')
                  q-item-section Submenu Label
                  q-item-section(side='side')
                    q-icon(name='keyboard_arrow_right')
                  q-menu(auto-close='auto-close', anchor='top end', self='top start')
                    q-list
                      q-item(v-for='n in 3', :key='n', dense='dense', clickable='clickable')
                        q-item-section 3rd level Label
          q-separator
          q-item(clickable='clickable', v-close-popup='v-close-popup')
            q-item-section Quit
</template>
```

I'm not able to open submenus.

The screenshot:

[image]

I'm not sure what I did wrong. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the mixin declaration where to render the block content that is passed to it. You can do that by adding `block` to the appropriate part of the mixin declaration. In your case, the declaration needs to be modified to be:

```
mixin createMenu(catalog)
  q-list(dense style='min-width: 100px')
    q-item(v-for='category in catalog', :key='category.permalink', href='#', clickable='clickable', v-close-popup='v-close-popup')
      q-item-section {{ category.title }}
      q-item-section(side='side')
        q-icon(name='keyboard_arrow_right', v-if='category.hasChildren')
      if block
        block
```

See [Mixin Blocks](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-blocks) in the Pug documentation for more info.